# Selecting limited range of node by using comment node as limiter

Tags: xpath

I was trying to select nodes between two comment

```
<ul>
  <!-- fromHere -->
  <option>a</option>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>a</option>
  <!-- toHere -->
  <option>a</option>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>a</option>
</ul>



$x("//comment()[.=' fromHere ']/following-sibling::* | //comment()[.=' toHere ']/preceding-sibling::*")
```

Is there anyway doing a AND selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `xpath`:

```
//option[preceding-sibling::comment()=" fromHere " and following-sibling::comment()=" toHere "]
```

Comment: the AND operator just returns a boolean value to me instead of nodes. Any idea? I am using chrome console to validate the code. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: `and` is inside `[]`. It means filter by two criteria

Comment: Oh,Thank you for mention that.Save me alot of time. It's done.